# How to implement java jdk14 record in jdk11?

Tags: java, java-11

I am looking to avoid some boilerplate code. I see that jdk14 has Records as shown in the example below.

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-14-changes/records.html

How can I do something similar to Records in jdk11 ?

Comment: Are you asking for a library to use here?

Comment: Actually, [Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) is a preview feature in Java 14. You must enable that feature, off by default. The specification is subject to change or withdrawal.

Comment: @Naman A lib or some custom code is what I was looking for. Thank you! The solutions below look promising.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend Project Lombok (site here https://projectlombok.org/). From the example you listed

```
 public record Person(String name, String gender, int age) {}
```

That can be done via Lombok like this

```
import lombok.Data

@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private int age;
}
```

Lombox creates getters and setters, `toString`, `hashCode`, and a default constructor, as well as one with all the orgs.

UPDATE: It was pointed out in the comments that records are immutable. You can easily achieve this with lombok in a couple of ways. Option 1:

```
import lombok.Data

@Data
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final String gender;
    private final int age;
}
```

That will add, again, the required-args constructor. `@Data` does not, for relatively obvious reasons, create setters for `final` fields.

Option 2 is a little more explicit:

```
import lombok.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: Java 14 records are immutable, so are autovalue objects.Lombox doesn't seem to offer that option.

Comment: I believe [`@Value` gets you closest to Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61306802/lombok-getter-setter-vs-java-14-record).

Comment: You actually could, @LeffeBrune. You could replace the `@Data` annotation and replace it with `@Constructor @Getters`, which would make them immutable.

Comment: what is `lombox` in imports ? and why is there `()` in class name `Person()` ?
It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @shubham `lombok` is a tool that generates methods at compile time. In the case of this example, it adds a constructor with `name`, `gender`, and `age` arguments, as well as `getX` methods for each, effectively allowing a user to set the values at construction time only. The `()` after `Person` are a typo. I'll fix, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Josh thanks i am familiar with Lombok and have used it extensively but I saw imports as `lombox` which got me confused. But now answer seems updated.

Comment: @shubham yep, just typos!

Answer (score 0):

You can use code generation. It's not as concise as Java 14, but better than nothing. [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) is pretty amazing.

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

@AutoValue
abstract class Animal {
  static Animal create(String name, int numberOfLegs) {
    return new AutoValue_Animal(name, numberOfLegs);
  }

  abstract String name();
  abstract int numberOfLegs();
}
```