# How to have a custom equals/hashCode for records?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, java-record

I have a record like:

```java
record Data(int x, int y, int a) {}
```

It gets default `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

---

How could I adjust those methods to have custom behavior? Lets say, I want to ignore `a` in the methods.

Comment: You should be able to just override them (but read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719753/133203))

Comment: Records still act like regular classes, you can just add or override methods as you like. So create the equals/hashcode methods yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is only one way to do this: You have to implement the methods yourself. Just overwrite these methods like you would do it with all other classes, too. In your own implementation, only use the properties you want. Your IDE usually helps you implement standard code and asks for the properties which should be included.

Alternatively, you can use tools like Lombok with annotations instead of implementation:

```java
@Data
public class Data{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude private int a;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, maybe add the final code in your answer? I.e. spend some effort writing a good quality answer? (see [answer])

Comment: Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` does not support records, only classes. I've created a feature request to change it, feel free to like/comment: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3246